# Rendering React components inside another div

Tags: reactjs

In React is it ok to render another component inside a div like this? And does the key go on the div?

```
dataArray.map((data) => {
       return (<div key = {data.id}>
                 <Person data = {data} />
               </div>)
})
```

Comment: That looks right, you can certainly do that.  If this is what the component is going to render, you would need to have the wrap the component with `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: You can return any dom node from a map. React needs a key to know which was which if one of them changes later, so just make sure to have some unique identifier that you can use as a key whenever you map over an array in React and output dom nodes.

Comment: Some of the answers you've received advise you to use the index value as your key. The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) cautions against this: _"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Person already returns jsx, then you can just do this if there is already an id in the data:

`dataArray.map(data => <Person key={data.id} data={data} />)`

If  not, you can use Ankit Sanghvi's technique:

`dataArray.map((data, idx) => <Person key={data.idx} data={data} />)`

Doing it this way gets rid of the extra nesting divs. I sense from your example that you think you need divs just to hold the key in the map but you actually don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your approach is correct.
For this, each data object in your `dataArray` must have a field called `id` (or you could use some other UUID value).
Else, a simpler approach could be using the object index in the iterated array:

```
    dataArray.map((data,id) => {
       return (<div key = {id}>
                 <Person data = {data} />
               </div>)
})
```

Comment: Note that the id in this example is actually the index of the element in the array being mapped and could change if the array is modified, so it's not really an "id". This is part of javascript Array.map and has nothing to do with React.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the approach which is usually followed. However, you should always use key attribute or react will give warnings in the console.

You can do so considering the following :-

```
    dataArray.map((data, index) => {
        return (
            <div key = {index}>
                <Person data = {data} />
           </div>
        )
    })
```